# Unity3D List error - Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can someone maybe help me with using lists in unity? I'm fairly new to them and currently im trying to implement a ballistics system in my game. Current setup is:

```
[SerializeField] List<Projectile> ProjectileInventory;
[SerializeField]Projectile currentprojectile;
[SerializeField]int projectileIndex;
Projectile MainCannon;
Projectile SecondaryCannon;
[SerializeField] int projectileCount;

private void Start()
{
MainCannon = new Projectile("Main Cannon", 2, 100, null, 20, true, true, false);
SecondaryCannon = new Projectile("Secondary Cannon", 0.1f, 1, null, 1, false, false, true);
ProjectileInventory.Add(MainCannon);
ProjectileInventory.Add(SecondaryCannon);
}
private void Update()
{
float mouseScroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
projectileCount = ProjectileInventory.Count;
if (projectileIndex > projectileCount - 1)
{
projectileIndex = 0;
return;
}
else if (projectileIndex < 0)
{
projectileIndex = projectileCount -1;
return;
}
if (mouseScroll > 0.1) projectileIndex++;
if (mouseScroll < -0.1) projectileIndex--;
if(currentprojectile != null) currentprojectile = ProjectileInventory[projectileIndex];
```

However i'm getting an error at the last line: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
I suppose that means that my variable projectileIndex is below zero or above ProjectileInventory.Count?
In unity the game plays fine and i can scroll through my list but as soon as i go below 0 or above the count of projectiles unity simply gives me the error in the title. Note: The list just works completely fine with selecting a currentprojectile from the list, even when the index is below zero it returns to the last projectile in the list.
I would very much appreciate if someone can help me with this :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your thought that the problem is with `projectileIndex` being less than 0 or greater than `ProjectileInventory.Count`.

If you  move the two `if(mouseScroll...` lines above the `if(projectileIndex >...` line you should be good.

You've got all the correct parts, just in the wrong order.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast response! This worked, so twice the thanks. i guess i messed up the order of the code, didn't think it was so important :).